# sed - How to get only the last line that was substituted?

Tags: macos, awk, sed

I'm trying to get a `sed`-only (or alternatively an `awk`-only) solution which only outputs the last line which matches the substitution pattern.

So far I have a solution which outputs only the lines that match the pattern, but I don't know how to extract only the last line of these remaining ones. I tried `$!d`, but it only extracts the last line from the initial input.

```
sed -E '/^.*\*\ *(Command Line Tools.*)\ *$/!d;s//\1/'
```

Sample Input:

```
Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2015 Apple Inc.

Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   * Command Line Tools (OS X 10.11) for Xcode-7.3
        Command Line Tools (OS X 10.11) for Xcode (7.3), 178678K [recommended]
   * Command Line Tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode-8.1
        Command Line Tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode (8.1), 123638K [recommended]
```

Sample Output:

```
Command Line Tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode-8.1
```

Comment: `s//\1/` is obviously pointless. What's the intention behind that?

Comment: Another thing. Why do you tag this with `awk` if you ask for a `sed-only` solution?

Comment: `s//\1/` is not pointless, it replaces the matching lines with the captured regex group `(Command Line.*)`.

I added the `awk` tag because an `awk`-only solution is also acceptable.

Comment: You think that works like that, but it isn't. Try `sed '/\(test\)/s//\1/' <<< '1test2'`. Furthermore, please make sure that your question's text fit's your requirements. Writing `sed-only` and meaning `sed/awk-only` is confusing. Since in the latter case it would be obviously `awk`

Comment: You're right, it doesn work like that, I didn't know that. But it does work in my case, as my pattern matches the whole line, like `sed -E '/^.*(test).*$/s//\1/' <<< '1test2'` would.

Comment: can you add a simple sample input of few lines and expected output to make it clearer for future users?

Comment: @reitermarkus Thx. I've learned something

Comment: @sundeep, added example input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following GNU `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/PATTERN/H;${x;s/.*\n//;p}' file
```

Explanation:

- `sed -n` Suppresses output by default
- `/PATTERN/` is the pattern you want to match
- `H` Appends the current, matching, line to the hold buffer
- `$` Addresses the last line of input (available only on GNU sed)
- `x` Exchange the contents of the hold and patter buffer
- `s/.*\n//` Replaces everything including the last newline in pattern buffer. This effectively leaves just the last match - as you've asked for.
- `p` Prints it.

Comment: Thanks, this got me in the right direction. Didn't know about the hold/pattern buffers. This is my final solution: `sed -E '/^.*\*\ *(Command Line Tools.*)\ *$/h;g;$!d;s//\1/'`

Answer (score 1):

`awk` will be straightforward

```
$ awk '/pattern/{p=$0} END{print p}' file
```

or with `tac` assist

```
$ tac file | awk '/pattern/{print; exit}'
```

can be incorporated with `sed` as well.

For replacing the line with the matched pattern, one alternative is

```
 $ awk '/pattern/{p=gensub(/.*(pattern).*/,"\\1",1)} END{print p}' file
```

or with similar transformation with `tac` version.

Comment: How would I use the pattern in this case to substitute the line?

Comment: substitute with what? you want to print something else, i.e. `/pattern/{print "substitute"}`

Comment: Substitute the line with the capture group in the regex pattern.